# How find string after special character with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have string on the variable and question is how find any character after `search/node/` and print that ?

String:

```
$var="search/node/Apartman";
```

my Codes :

```
$var="search/node/Apartment";    //URL

preg_match('/search/node/\K\d+/', $var,$newvar);

$FinalVAR=$newvar[0];

print_r ($FinalVAR);
```

BUT NOT WORK

THANKS FOR ANY HELP.

Comment: `preg_match('/search\/node\/(.*)/', $var,$newvar)`. then $newvar[1] should be what you need? Basically you need to escape the `/` in your pattern

Comment: Something like `'~search/node/\K[^/]+~'`

Comment: Not work my friend !

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks man....

Comment: I removed the first `\/` in my comment above, it works as shown below.

Comment: $var="search/node/Apartment";    //URL

preg_match("/\bsearch\/node\b(.*)/", $var, $newvar);

$FinalVAR=ltrim($newvar[1],'/');

print_r ($FinalVAR);

Comment: $var="search/node/Apartment";    //URL

preg_match("/\bsearch\/node\b(.*)/", $var, $newvar);

$FinalVAR=ltrim($newvar[1],'/');

print_r ($FinalVAR);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `/` as the delimiter, `/` in the pattern should be escaped. or use other rarely used char as delimiter, such as `~`. The working code:

```
$var="search/node/Apartman";

preg_match('/search\/node\/(.*)/', $var,$newvar);

var_export($newvar);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 'search/node/Apartman',
  1 => 'Apartman',
)
```